# ENOENT while using R pkgdown

Tags: r

Cloning the v 1.1.0 of [pkgdown](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/tree/v1.1.0) and trying to run `pkgdown::build_site()` gives me the following error:

```sh
> pkgdown::build_site()
══ Building pkgdown site ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reading from: '/home/farm/Documents/pkgdown-1.1.0'
Writing to:   '/home/farm/Documents/pkgdown-1.1.0/docs'
── Initialising site ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Writing 'sitemap.xml'
── Building home ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
<ENOENT: [ENOENT] Failed to remove '/tmp/Rtmp0utBMA/file114d619b1b68.html': no such file or directory>
Error: [ENOENT] Failed to remove '/tmp/Rtmp0utBMA/file114d619b1b68.html': no such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Most likely is a problem with my Linux and R, not the package itself. That being said, this is the environment:

- R: 3.5.1
- Manjaro: 18.0.0-rc

How can I fix this? I'm trying to avoid using `chmod -R 777 /tmp/`

**note**: I also ran `devtools::test()` and `devtools::check()`, no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to build a package from scratch, I found my mistake... Pandoc was missing, installing it from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pandoc-bin/) fixed it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pandoc` worked for me in Debian (using RStudio Server).